# The second rise of the sandworm

Tags: dune, evolution, sandworm

In *God Emperor of Dune* by Frank Herbert, Leto states that when his 'metamorphosis' into a sandworm is complete, he will return to the sand. He goes on to say that the sandworms that would come from his metamorphosis would posses qualities from both him and the sandworm.

***For example:***

1. The sandworms would have at least a pseudo-brain. *Derived from Leto's body, which was fused with that of the sandtrout.*
2. Parts of his consciousness would live within each individual sandworm.

Although Leto was absorbed into the pre-sandworm body, he and the worm are not the same *a.* being, *b.* species (by extension).

It seems extremely unlikely that the next *wave*, for lack of a better term, of sandworms, would have the brain tissue that was introduced by Leto, much less the circulatory and respiratory systems to support it.

***Why would Leto's sandworm 'offspring', have characteristics of himself, when in reality, he was merely a parasite in the worms body?***

Comment: he was no longer a parasite, he actively fused to the sandtrout, and became a sandworm

Comment: @Himarm, this certainly doesn't mean they are the same species, unless the sandtrout somehow had the foresight and means to interact with his DNA on the cellular level, which is not indicated in any of Frank Herbert's works.

Comment: no but the bene gesserit and KWISATZ HADERACH are able to work at a DNA level, and he merged himself with the Sandtrout and became a singular entity. so all future sandworms based on sandtrout from his body share his DNA.

Comment: essentially the sandtrout where the parasite, and he merged them into himself. he no longer had a human body underneath the street.

Comment: It was never really broken down in the books, but there are other possibilities, such as his nerve tissue remaining with the worm cells (the way they think Mitocondria fused with out cells, long, long ago.)

Comment: *Leto?* The only reason I kept reading the long winded Dune series is because I thought the guy's name was *Lego.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why would Leto's sandworm 'offspring', have characteristics of
>   himself, when in reality, he was merely a parasite in the worms body?

If you are looking for an in-universe answer then revisit your assumption that he was "merely a parasite". The books imply a much more complex interaction than the word parasite implies in our current world.
The sandworms are likely an entirely alien species. Assuming they even used DNA at all and that it works anything similar to "earth" DNA is just an assumption.

If you are looking for a more rational real-world explanation (as implied by the technical tone of your question and comments) then please be aware that the Dune series is [famous for being a land-mark example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Herbert#Status_and_influence_on_science_fiction) of "[soft science fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_science_fiction)". That is sci-fi that doesn't try to be scientifically realistic.
Also bear in mind that Herbert had no formal scientific education or experience and was much more interested in mysticism.
Also bear in mind that DNA was still not very familiar to the general public as he started writing the first Dune book around the time Watson, Crick, and Wilkins got the Nobel Prize for their DNA work.

Answer (score 3):

I think answer is multi-part, methinks.

One - Leto is *Kwisatz Haderach*, albeit a "rogue" one. Effect of millenia-old breeding program, with literally unknown capabilities. We know of some, but obviously it means that outcome of that program would not be a human being as the term was understood.

Two - Leto was subjected to "spice treatment" at Jacurutu. Melange intake has known effects, which can only be possible if working on genetic level. Mechanisms of it's workings are unknown (or at least not much info in the books on that), so it's entirely possible this treatment has some effect on cellular/genetic level in Leto's body. Maybe spice acted as a catalyst?

Three - The consciousness of Leto in worms may equally well be the effect of genetic mutation. Exchange/retention of genetic material - one way, both ways, whatever - is hardly a novel concept, especially for Nature... And for all we know sandworms had full-blown genetic memory trait and caused the semi-self-aware state of later worms?

Four - the pivotal role in the transformation was Leto's ability to control own body with his mind and knowledge what to do coming from is genetic memory.

I'd say evolution rather than parasitic or even symbiotic coexistence

Comment: Leto was a red Kwisatz Haderach? ;) should be rogue not rouge, id have edited it but cant for such a minor change